# Impala query returning incorrect results in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get count of an Impala table from pyspark. But I am getting improper results in spark.

The impala table is a partitioned table. It is partitioned on year and month (**EX: 201906**).  I am even doing a Invalidate metadata,alter table recover partitions and refresh table after updating the table. But I still dont get proper results in spark.

Executing

```
select count(*) dbname.tablename where timestamp>='2019-06-01' and timestamp<='2019-06-15'
```

returns

```
10931
```

and

```
spark.sql("select count(*) dbname.tablename") where timestamp>='2019-06-01' and timestamp<='2019-06-15'
```

returns

```
0
```

Answer (score 1):

The tables it's parquet one and write the rows from Impala?
If yes, the answer is [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_spark_ki.html#tsb_2018_300).

> Missing results in Hive, Spark, Pig, Custom MapReduce jobs, and other Java applications when filtering Parquet data written by Impala